# Custom field in Workflow model

Tags: java, alfresco

I'm customizing Alfresco Share.
I would like to add a new field called "Subject" when starting new workflows. I added  changes to `workflowModel.xml` for content modelling. `share-config-custom.xml` to customize the view of starting-workflow-form.

The problem is how can I view the saved data(new field Subject) from other places(eg workflow details). I'm doubting I need to change `WorkflowInstance.java` as well.

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Following files are needed to modified.

```
workflowModel.xml // to add property to exisiting workflow

WorkflowModelBuilder.java
WorkflowObjectFactory.java
WorkflowInstance.java

workflow-list.js
workflow.lib.ftl
```

The new fields are required to add as new attributes in WorkflowInstance

Comment: You should not have to make all of these changes to see workflow metadata. Maybe I don't understand where you need to see subject, but if it is just on the start workflow page and the workflow details, you should not have to touch Java or client-side JS to make that happen.